# Expansion and formatting commands

Tags: expansion

I'm trying to accomplish something similar to autoref, but more customizable.  In particular, I'm making a command which takes in a name for a label, and the text that should be output when that label is referenced.  Then using the package hyperref, one can easily create a command that outputs the desired text:

```
\newcommand{\hlink}[1]{\hyperref[label text #1]{\csname label text #1\endcsname}}
```

All of that background isn't really the issue.  The issue is that sometimes thinks like font choice muck this up.  Really the issue is how to expand and save temporary info without expanding things like font choice.  In particular, I can currently can assign the link text to the label text as follows:  suppose `\tempinfo` is some temporary information that I want stored.

```
\def\tempinfo{AAA}

\expandafter\label{label text \tempinfo}
\expandafter\xdef\csname label text \tempinfo\endcsname{blah link text \tempinfo}
```

Now `\tempinfo` is saved in the command.  If I change `\tempinfo`, I still get the same output:

```
\csname label text AAA\endcsname\\
\def\tempinfo{BBB}
\csname label text AAA\endcsname
```

outputs

> blah link text AAA
>   blah link text AAA

So far so good, but what if instead of `blah link text` I want `$\mathrm{blah}$` or `\textit{italics}`?  I can't use `\xdef` (or `\edef`)  anymore without encountering errors.  But if I just use `\def`, `\tempinfo` isn't saved.  Running the same stuff as before but with "`\xdef`" replaced by "`\def`" yields

> blah link text AAA
>   blah link text BBB

So I'm not sure if there's a way to get past this issue, or if there's a better solution available that I haven't found yet.

EDIT:  Here's an example.  Currently, `\hlink` returns `The Example Theorem (0.1)` without any formatting on "Example", and I'd like to be able to have it (for example) be italicized, or in \mathrm, or something of that sort.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\newcommand{\labeldef}[2]{%
    \def\templabelname{#1}%
    \label{label text \templabelname}%
    \expandafter\xdef\csname label text \templabelname\endcsname{#2}%
}

\newcommand{\hlink}[1]{%
    \ifcsname label text #1\endcsname%
        \hyperref[label text #1]{\csname label text #1\endcsname}%
    \else%
        [MISSING LINK FOR “#1”]%
    \fi%
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{theorem}[The \textit{Example} Theorem] 
        theorem text theorem text...
    \end{theorem}

    \labeldef{examplethm}{The Example Theorem (\arabic{section}.\arabic{theorem})}

    \begin{theorem}
        theorem text theorem text...
    \end{theorem}

    The ideal reference: \hyperref[label text examplethm]{The \textit{Example} Theorem (0.1)}

    Referencing the above with the new command: \hlink{examplethm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note: the `\expandafter` in `\expandafter\label{label text \tempinfo}` does nothing.  Nonetheless, could you provide us a **complete** working example to play with?

Comment: I'm not sure how you intend to use this. Can you please be more specific with an example usage?

Comment: The general idea is that some theorems have names (with math and sometimes formatting), and rather than reference them by location (e.g. "theorem II.25") I'd prefer to reference the name (e.g. "The Example Theorem (II.25)").  The theorem name would be set by the user, but the location would ideally be saved as well.  I'll edit in a more complete example.

Comment: Could you please extend your MWE to actually demonstrate the use of your temporary information in the newly defined command? In what way should `\tempinfo´ be integrated into the command's replacement text?

Comment: @siracusa  That would be the location information, e.g. \arabic{section}, and \arabic{theorem}. With `def` instead of `xdef` the wrong theorem number is given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're asking an XY-question.

The mechanism is already there, namely `\nameref`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\nnref}[1]{\nameref{#1}~(\ref{#1})}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[The \textit{Example} Theorem]\label{tet}
theorem text theorem text...
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}
theorem text theorem text...
\end{theorem}

The ideal reference: \nnref{tet}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

An easy solution to fix your specific expansion problem is to split the location part into another argument and add it back into the replacement text at the right position:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\newcommand{\labeldef}[3]{%
    \def\templabelname{#1}%
    \label{label text \templabelname}%
    \edef\temp{%
        \gdef\csname label text \templabelname\endcsname{\unexpanded{#2} (#3)}%
    }\temp
}

\newcommand{\hlink}[1]{%
    \ifcsname label text #1\endcsname%
        \hyperref[label text #1]{\csname label text #1\endcsname}%
    \else%
        [MISSING LINK FOR “#1”]%
    \fi%
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{theorem}[The \textit{Example} Theorem] 
        theorem text theorem text...
    \end{theorem}

    \labeldef{examplethm}{The \textit{Example} Theorem}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{theorem}}

    \begin{theorem}
        theorem text theorem text...
    \end{theorem}

    The ideal reference: \hyperref[label text examplethm]{The \textit{Example} Theorem (0.1)}

    Referencing the above with the new command: \hlink{examplethm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The temporary command `\temp` fully expands the new command name and location parameter, but leaves the theorem name unexpaned such that you can use all kind of macros in it.